# Run A Specific Jupyter Notebook On Start

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to setup a system such that it not only runs `jupyter notebook` on start, but it also starts executing a specific notebook on that jupyter server (running all cells in sequence).

Is this possible?  I specifically want to be able to access the notebook web interface and inspect/stop/etc the running notebook at any point.

I know `nbconvert` can execute a notebook, but it seems to run independently of any existing jupyter servers?

Maybe there is some API I can access so that I can write a shell script to run `jupyter notebook` and then use the API to open and run a notebook?

Comment: Yeah. I have the same problem. 
I want to run all cells at the open stage.